# How to have jQuery accordian return to starting position (Currently returning on top of one-another)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, math

I'm really new to this stuff and I could really do with someones help.

I have a js fiddle set up here: http://jsfiddle.net/hAZR7/

The issue I have is more a logic / math one I think as it seems to animate fine and start and move to the desired position. I'ts the return that has me stumped and I am not sure what equation or code I need to fix it. (Even though it is probably staring me in the face).

Would I be right in thinking this has something to do with it? when removing the class 'on' but what to set the margin as to calculate where it should return to.

```
$elm.removeClass('on');
var $left_margin = $extra_margin;
$elm.stop().animate({marginLeft : $left_margin}, 1500, function()
     {$slider_started = false;});
```

**Update** - Thanks for your answers both examples work fine one adjusting slight dimensions in CSS but I don't think it is detrimental to the functionality. Is there any way of implementing this into a setInterval / automation for the slides or should I raise another question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seee this : http://jsfiddle.net/bt9Je/

Changes:

```
var $total_slider = $j('.top-slider-main > div').length;
```

and

```
var $left_margin = $extra_margin-((($total_slider-i))*$label_width);
```

Comment: Thanks A.V, I have the return i need with my tabs lined up neatly. Are you able to see the tab removed to the far end of the container?

I have the tab reaching the end of it's animation just short of the right hand side is this down to the $left_margin being set?

Comment: I'm sorry A.V, you where right the code works it's just my CSS calling for the width of top-slider-main and it not being enough to return the margin I need for the tab to sit on the far right when the animation is finished.

My example can be seen here; http://jsfiddle.net/bHJYB/

Again thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can change

```
var $left_margin = $extra_margin;
```

to

```
if( $elm.next().length ) {
    var $left_margin = $elm.next().offset().left - $label_width;
} else {
    var $left_margin = $j('.top-slider-main').first().width() - $label_width;
}
```

**Edit** To fix the bug described in the comment change the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hAZR7

```
var $total_slider = $j('.top-slider-main div').length;
```

to

```
var $total_slider = $j('.top-slider-main  > div').length;
```

and line

```
var $left_margin = $extra_margin;
```

to

```
var $left_margin = $j('.top-slider-main').first().width() -  ( ( $total_slider - i + 1 ) * $label_width );
```

I've forked the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gU2Tq/

Comment: Hi Domen, your code allows the return to sit exactly where I need it to go and I was tinkering around to get something similar but felt like it didn't work well as if a user clicks a tab before the current tab has reached the end of the div, it slows to a crawl and breaks.

Do you know if i'm placing this code in the wrong place? I have though it was the left = extra part;

here; http://jsfiddle.net/tbf5u/

Comment: You've placed the code on the right location it's just that I haven't noticed the bug before... I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Domen, your code seems to fix this also and without having to adjust any CSS and width of the slide. Would there be any knock on affect should I adjust the CSS width? (Also as a new guy to this place whats the typical thing to do when both answers seem to fix the issue?).

The only thing I need to look at implementing is the automation of this jQuery ** See question Edit

Comment: You could just upvote both answers. As for the update I'd suggest that you create a new question.